# External Table in Databricks is showing only future date data

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I had a delta table in databricks and data is available in ADLS. data is partitioned by date column, from 01-06-2022 onwards data is available in parquet format in adls but when i query the table in databricks i can see data from future date onwards everyday.older data is not displaying. every day data is overwriting to the table path with partitioned date column.

Comment: Can you share the code snippet what you are using to write the data to ADLS.

Comment: df.write.format('delta').mode('overwrite').save('{}/{}'.format(DELTALAKE_PATH, table))

Comment: I can see the data is in adls ,,if i try reading the files i can only read future dates .. when i try reading older date data i'm getting path doesnot exits error

Comment: I dont see the partition by column defined in the above query you have pasted.

Comment: table is created with partitioned date column

Answer (score 1):

```
df.write.format('delta').mode('overwrite').save('{}/{}'.format(DELTALAKE_PATH, table))
```

Using Overwrite mode will delete past data and add new data. This is the reason for your issue.

```
df.write.format('delta').mode('append').save('{}/{}'.format(DELTALAKE_PATH, table))
```

Using append mode will append new data beneath the existing data. This will keep your existing data and when you execute a query, it will return past records as well.

You need to use append mode in place of overwrite mode.

**Append Mode** - Only the new rows appended in the Result Table since the last trigger will be written to the external storage. This is applicable only to queries where existing rows in the Result Table are not expected to change.

Reference - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#basic-concepts

Comment: it's much simpler to use `f'{DELTALAKE_PATH}/{table}'` instead of`'{}/{}'.format(DELTALAKE_PATH, table)`